# Converting date format in denodo database

Tags: dbeaver, denodo

I'm trying to convert value for DIM_DT_ID to MMddYY. I'm successful in doinf that. However, query fails because ultimately I'm comparing a character value to date here. Is there a way by which I can get value for DIM_DT_ID in MMddyy format and its data type still remains DATE ?
Here DIM_DT_ID 
SELECT DIM_DT_ID
DIM_DT_ID      >= FORMATDATE('MMddyy',ADDDAY(TO_date('yyyy-MM-dd','2016-12-21'), -25)); from abc;
Regards,
Ajay

Comment: What is DIM_DT_ID?  Is it a number?  What do some of the values of that field look like?

Answer (score 0):

In Denodo, to convert a string to a date field, use "to_date()" (which returns a date).

Then, don't convert back to a string, leave that field as a date (so don't use "Formatdate()", which returns a string).

So:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE now() >= to_date('yyyy-MM-dd',myStringFieldThatLooksLikeADate)
```

In my example, "now()" is a date, and so is the output of the to_date function... so you can do a comparison.

If you try to convert the date back to a string using formatdate, it won't work:

```
#This doesn't work:
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE now() >= formatdate('MMddyy',to_date('yyyy-MM-dd',myStringFieldThatLooksLikeADate))
```

It doesn't work because we are comparing a date ("now()") to a string.

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried this but the issue is that I want to compare date in MMddYY format.

Comment: I don't understand... usually you compare two date objects... the format is a non-issue because the format is usually just a human readable representation of the underlying object.  So, if you want to compare two date objects, you need to make sure both objects are dates... in Denodo, you convert a string to a date with "to_date()".  What is the other object type?  Is it a string?  Is it a number?  If you want to compare it as a date, it will need to be converted to a date first.

Comment: Yes. Initially i used to_date. However, just with to_date I cannot convert the date format from 'yyyy-MM-dd' to MMddYY. That is where my issue is.

Comment: Because i use this in java code for comparison. Java code expect the date format to be MMddYY.